# ReactJS - Get onMouseMove and onMouseEnter to work togher

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, mouseevent

What I'm trying to build is a card with a photo as a background image. The idea is that when I hover on the photo (MouseEnter) the photo changes from a black and white one, to a colored one, but when I move the mouse horizontally on the photo the background image changes to another photo (the effect is similar to the apple album preview).

Now I got the code to work, but when I enter with the mouse on the photo the effect of the mouse enter is not even visible, because the mouse move function triggers right after that.

So the effect I want to get is: when I move the mouse over the photo, it changes to a colored one. THEN when I move the mouse again the scroll effect starts to work and I can change photo scrolling.

Here is the code:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import $ from 'jquery';

const AboutCard = ({id, name, role, description, link, image, colored_image}) => {
  const [backImg, setBackImg] = useState(0);
  
  var active = 0;
  var currentProfile = 0;
  var unitPhoto= 0;
  const handeMouseEnter = (event) => {
    setBackImg(colored_image);
  };
  const handleMouseMove = (event) => {
    unitPhoto = 100/(image.length-1);
    var offset = $('#'+event.target.attributes.id.value).offset();
    let x = event.pageX- offset.left;
    let w =$('#'+event.target.attributes.id.value).width();
    x = (x*100)/w;
    let index = Math.floor(x/unitPhoto);
    
    if(index >= image.length){
      index = image.length-1;
    }
    if(index <0){
      return;
    }
    if(index !== active || index != colored_image){
      setBackImg(index);
      active = index;
    }
  };

  const handleTouchMove = (event) => {
    unitPhoto = 100/(image.length-1);
    var offset = $('#'+event.target.attributes.id.value).offset();
    let x = event.touches[0].pageX- offset.left;
    let w = $('#'+event.target.attributes.id.value).width();
    x = (x*100)/w;
    let index = Math.floor(x/unitPhoto);
    if(index === 0){
      setBackImg(colored_image);
      return;
    }
    if(index >= image.length-1){
      index = image.length-2;
    }
    if(index <0){
      return;
    }
    if(index !== active || index !== colored_image){
      setBackImg(index);
      active = index;
    }     
  };

  $(document).on('mousemove', function(event){
    if($('#'+event.target.attributes.id.value).attr('class') !== 'profileImage'){
      setBackImg(0);
    }
  })

  $(document).on('touchend', function(){
    setBackImg(0);
  })

  return (
    <div className="aboutDiv" id={id}>
      <Link to={`${link}`}>
        <div 
          onMouseEnter={(ev) => handeMouseEnter(ev)} 
          onMouseMove={(ev)=> handleMouseMove(ev)} 
          onTouchMove={(ev)=> 
          handleTouchMove(ev)} 
          id={'image-'+id} 
          style={{ 
            background: `url(${image[backImg]})`,
          }} 
          className="profileImage"
        >
        </div> 
      </Link>
      <h3 className="profileName">{name}</h3>
      <p className="profileRole">{role}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AboutCard;
```

Any tips?

Comment: I can't understand why you add jquery events like `$(document).on('mousemove'...` on every render? Maybe better it's using `useEffect` and destroying event function on destroy (anonymous fn not) and I think it's not good practice mix jquery events and React events `<div onMouseEnter={(ev) => handeMouseEnter(ev)}`

Comment: @zbyso yeah I know, I'm new to react and I'm trying to learn things slowly mixing the knowledge in js with that, but I know is not a good practice. But in this particular case have u any ideas on how to get a solution to this problem that I wrote about?

Comment: it's possible to setup your example to https://codesandbox.io/ or something like this?